# User ID Number -1

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, community-user

How come the [Community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user has the user id number of -1? Is this [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) or is it a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)? I don't know about other sites, but here it is -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's intentional, to represent that the Community user is an automated process instead of an actual account controlled by a human. On [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/), the Feeds users that emit RSS feeds all have negative IDs for the same reason ([Feeds](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-2), [Gaming Feed](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-3), [Gaming Meta Feed](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-4), etc.)

Comment: If he's not a "real user", how come he can post questions? HOW COME??!?? http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1665/2011-community-moderator-election

Comment: @Juan SOIS is slowly losing control of it. They're keeping it quiet to avoid panic

Comment: You shouldn't have said that. Now its going to come after you!